# I dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 10 and now my Ubuntu is running very weird and making a lot of sounds

Tags: dual-boot, overheating

I recently Dual Booted Ubuntu with Windows 10 and now my Ubuntu machine is running slower than I expected and its really weird, sometimes out of nowhere it just makes tons of noise like overheating and getting no airflow, and I have no idea why. I do actually think it could be because an application I installed called "Hollywood" and I installed it and then unexpected crashes started to happen and pop up on my screen and now I need some help to make my PC run normal again like it should be doing.

Comment: Should mention what hardware and ubuntu version you have when asking, different versions and hardware can make a difference for answers.  Did Ubuntu work well before installing 'hollywood', or was it not as good as expected?

Comment: Look in /var/crash for details about crashes and what to do about them. Look up how to install various packages (like `lm-sensors`) to monitor the temperature of your hardware components. Use the `top` application to identify applications that seem to be using too many resources.